# Better restructure of getting the label values from Schema class?

Tags: apex, dynamic-apex

I am sending the coulumn header values for the treegrid in my lightning treegrid component. I am pulling the label values from Schema class. I am a newbie and I am not sure if I can restructure the way of fetching the values from Schema class in a better way than how I am already fetching. Could someone suggest me a better way. Thanks

```
public static List<ColumnParam> createColumns() {

        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult accountDescribe = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = accountDescribe.fields.getMap();
        String Or1;
        String Or2;
        String Or3;
        String OrNumber;
        Or1 = fieldMap.get('Organisation1__c').getDescribe().getLabel();
        Or2 = fieldMap.get('Organisation2__c').getDescribe().getLabel();
        Or3 = fieldMap.get('Organisation3__c').getDescribe().getLabel();
        OrNumber = fieldMap.get('Organisation4__c').getDescribe().getLabel();

        List<ColumnParam> columnParams = new List<ColumnParam>();
        columnParams.add(
                new ColumnParam(
                        'text',
                        'Org1',
                        Or1,
                        150
                )
        );
        columnParams.add(
                new ColumnParam(
                        'text',
                        'Org2',
                        Or2,
                        150
                )
        );
        columnParams.add(
                new ColumnParam(
                        'text',
                        'Org3',
                        Or3,
                        150
                )
        );
        columnParams.add(
                new ColumnParam(
                        'text',
                        'OrgNumber',
                        OrNumber,
                        220
                )
        );
        return columnParams;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could work directly from the fields via the [SObjectField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_field_tokens.htm) tokens, skip some of the variables, and use the list initializer syntax:

```
public static List<ColumnParam> createColumns() {
    return new List<ColumnParam>{
        new ColumnParam(
            'text',
            'Org1',
            Account.Organisation1__c.getDescribe().getLabel(),
            150
        ),
        new ColumnParam(
            'text',
            'Org2',
            Account.Organisation2__c.getDescribe().getLabel(),
            150
        ),
        new ColumnParam(
            'text',
            'Org3',
            Account.Organisation3__c.getDescribe().getLabel(),
            150
        ),
        new ColumnParam(
            'text',
            'OrgNumber',
            Account.Organisation4__c.getDescribe().getLabel(),
            220
        )
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) I have learnt something new today

Comment: @user3920709 You are welcome; takes a while to understand the describe mechanism.